# Use java operator :: dynamically

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following implementation:

```
private SomeWritter someWritter(String someArgument) {
    SomeWritter.Builder builder = SomeWritter.builder(someArguments);
    builder = builder.addColumn("colName1", TargetClass::getArg1)
    builder = builder.addColumn("colName2", TargetClass::getArg2)
    return builder.build();
}

private Builder<T> addColumn(String colName, ToDoubleFunction<T> getter){
   //implementation goes here
}
```

my issue is that I need to iterate over the addColumns call, something among these lines:

```
private void SomeWritter(String someArgument) {
    SomeWritter.Builder builder = SomeWritter.builder(someArguments);
    for (Field field : getFilteredFieldsFromClass(TargetClass.class)) {
        builder = builder.addColumn(field.getName(), [SOMEHOW GET THE REF TO GETTER HERE])
    }
    return builder.build();
}
```

in order to get the refference to the getter, I tryed to do
TargetClass.class.getMethod("getArg1", ...);

this works, but I have a Method, not a ToDoubleFunction.

I need to somehow get that ToDoDoubleFunction, programatically, I want to do the same that the TargetClass:: does, dinamically, not harcoded. any ideas ?

Comment: addColum takes some functional interface as second parameter. You can use a lambda to implement this interface. In the {} of the lambda use the reflection.

Comment: in the first implementation I am passing as a parameter TargetClass::getArg1, how do I implement an interface using a lamda expression that behaves in the same way as TargetClass::getArg1? I dont get it

Comment: (target)-> field.get(target) or similar https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_lambda.asp

Comment: object::function is called a method reference and is the super short form of implementing an interface(in your case ToDoubleFunction). The longer and more flexible/powerfull form is a lambda. https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-lambda-expressions-tips

Comment: can you share a code snippet with me ? 
whats the lamda version of TargetClass::getArg1 ?

Comment: I can only guess because there is a lot of stuff missing in your little code snippet. That is definitely not minimal Example.
My guess would be "(target)-> target.getArg1()"

Comment: now I understand what youre saying. TargetClass::getArg1 is the same as (TargetClass) -> TargetClass.getArg1().     I agree on that, but this is still by extension, and not dinamically. How can I write these lambda expressions dinamically ?

Comment: the name inside the () in a lambda can be freely chosen. Normally you name your variable lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Main {
  static class Example{
    double arg1;
    int arg2;
  }
  
  interface Foo<T>{
    double toDouble(T example);
  }
  
  public static void addColumn(Foo<Example> foo){
    //do nothing
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final var example = new Example();
    
    for(Field field: Example.class.getDeclaredFields()){
      addColumn(example1 -> {
        try {
          return (double) field.get(example1);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

That code iterates over all fields of the Example class and uses the reflection inside a lambda.
Side Note. Intellij can replace method references with lambda when you click alt+enter when cursor is on them (Windows).
[image: replace with lambda]

Comment: Well Alex, its easy to see you handle this topic very well, this worled perfectly, and once !

Thanks a lot, and have a very nice day.